# Updating to Ubuntu Studio

Tags: dual-boot, upgrade, desktop-environments, ubuntu-studio

I would like to install Ubuntu Studio on my computer which has currently a dual boot Ubuntu_13.04/Windows_7. Surfing in the internet I saw that it is possible to upgrade Ubuntu to Ubuntu Studio. The question is: doing the update, will I lose the current Ubuntu 13.04 OS?

For example, when installing gnome-desktop on unity, you have the possibility of choosing between the two of them when booting the system.

Is it the same in this case? If I upgrade to Ubuntu Studio installing ubuntustudio-desktop, the proper packages and the proper low-latency kernel, will I still have the possibility of choosing between GNOME, Unity and Ubuntu Studio during the boot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu Studio, like all flavors of Ubuntu (including Ubuntu itself) have all their packages in the same repositories, so you can install them on top of each other. 
There is no need however, to install the Ubuntu Studio desktop, unless you want.

To prepare Ubuntu for pro audio, this is all you need to do:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntustudio-audio linux-lowlatency
```

Make sure to answer "yes", when asked about realtime privilege, while installing jackd. If you already installed it, make sure the file /etc/security/limits.d/audio.conf is not named /etc/security/limits.d/audio.conf.disabled. If so, rename it to the former.
Finally, in order to get the benfit of realtime privilege on Ubuntu, you need to add yourself to audio group. In a terminal:

```
sudo usermod -a -G audio $USER
```

If you also would like to try the Ubuntu Studio desktop, install it as well (it has a custom menu that you might find useful):

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntustudio-desktop
```

It won't replace Unity. When logging in, click the CoF button (the icon) to choose which desktop environment to login to.

Reboot. Make sure you boot into the lowlatency kernel. Enjoy!